# SwiftUI NavigationView/Stack if available iOS 15/16

Tags: xcode, swiftui, navigationview, ios16

There's something I don't really understand about the transition from `NavigationView` to `NavigationStack` for SwiftUI 4 and iOS 16.

I have 2 applications running on the App Store (targeting iOS 15 and above) and of course I'm using `NavigationView`. This weekend, I was looking for a solution to have them ready for iOS 16 by replacing:

```
var body: some View {
   NavigationView {
      ScrollView { /* code here */ }
   }
}
```

To something like this:

```
var body: some View {
   if #available(iOS 16, *) {
      NavigationStack {
   } else {
      NavigationView {
   }
      ScrollView { /* code here */ }
   }
}
```

But finally, before doing so, I tried them with iOS 16 Beta and they're perfectly fine.
I don't understand, I thought it would be total a mess but finally no. Do you have an explanation? Maybe, deprecated isn't what it should mean?

Comment: If you're looking for the solution btw: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73700850/swiftui-navigationview-vs-navigationstack-for-ios-15-16

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NavigationView` is ***deprecated***, not ***obsoleted***. When a component becomes ***deprecated***, it still can be used until **Apple** decides to ***obsolete*** it which will cause a crash when used. Although it's functional, you shouldn't use it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Timmy. I really appreciate the clarification. I think I'll push an update with `NavigationStack`. I'm just wondering if my second piece of code is ok? Or if there's a better way to make it works also for iOS 15 with `NavigationView`.

Comment: I suggest you create a custom container, otherwise it is absolutely okay!

Comment: Alright, that's all I needed to know. Thanks again @Timmy. ✌️