# SwiftUI EditButton in NavigationView not activating edit mode

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

In full view, it is impossible to edit that particular list. The edit button functionality is not appeared in my latest Xcode version (14.0)

```
import SwiftUI

struct ListTutorialBootcamp: View {
    
    func delete(indexSet: IndexSet) {
        fruits.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
    }
    
    @State private var fruits: [String] = ["Apple", "banana", "grape", "Orange", "Peach"]
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
               
                    ForEach(fruits, id: \.self)  {
                        fruit in Text(fruit.capitalized)
                    }
                    .onDelete(perform: delete)
                   
                
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Grocery List")
        .navigationBarItems(leading: EditButton())
       
    }
}

struct ListTutorialBootcamp_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ListTutorialBootcamp()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `navigationTitle` and `navigationBarItems` modifiers on your `List` instead of `NavigationView`.

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            ForEach(fruits, id: \.self) { fruit in
                Text(fruit.capitalized)
            }
            .onDelete(perform: delete)                
        }
        .navigationTitle("Grocery List")
        .navigationBarItems(leading: EditButton())
    }
}
```

**Note:-** If you are targeting `iOS16` as the minimum version then use the new [`NavigationStack`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationstack) instead of the deprecated `NavigationView`.

Comment: Great answer! `NavigationView` modifiers can't be on NavigationView itself but on any child you want. Also, if you're looking to target both iOS 15 and 16 with `NavigationStack` here's a possibility: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73701150/18547664

Comment: Thanks ! It solved my problem, I kept the navigation view as it should be, but the problem was about putting the title and bar items in the correct place.